# How to free object from member function?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management

Let's day I have a Test class which has a factory function registered to construct the object. Because I need to embed this object in a script engine. So the factory function is responsible for allocating memory for the object and creating an instance of the Test class.

The object is reference counted so it must destruct itself and also free  the memory allocated by the factory function when the counter reaches 0. And it must do this from a member function.

This is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
#include <memory>
#include <cstdio>

class Test
{
public:
    typedef std::allocator<Test> Allocator;

    Test()
        : m_Ref(1)
    {
        // Constructing....
    }

    ~Test()
    {
        // Destructing....
    }

    static Test *Create()
    {
        Allocator::pointer ptr = 0;
        Allocator alloc;

        try
        {
            ptr = alloc.allocate(1);
            alloc.construct(ptr);
        }
        catch (const std::bad_alloc &ba)
        {
            // Propagate the error message to the script engine...
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            alloc.deallocate(ptr, 1);
            ptr = 0;
            // Propagate the error message to the script engine...
        }

        return ptr;
    }

    void AddRef()
    {
        m_Ref++;
    }
    void SubRef()
    {
        if (--m_Ref == 0)
        {
            Allocator alloc;
            alloc.destroy(this);
            alloc.deallocate(this, 1);
        }
    }
    int RefSum()
    {
        return m_Ref;
    }
private:
    mutable int m_Ref;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Script would call
    Test *ptr = Test::Create();

    // Use the object (as an example)
    printf("Ref count is: %d\n", ptr->RefSum());

    // Now to release
    ptr->SubRef();

    // The object must not exist now...
    printf("Ref count is: %d\n", ptr->RefSum());

    return 0;
}
```

So my question is: When m_Ref reaches 0 and the object is destructed and deallocated, is the previously allocated memory freed or not?

If not, then how do I deallocate the memory allocated with std::allocator::allocate() when m_Ref reaches 0.

Comment: Have you considered using `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: I cannot use that. Like I said, the object must implement reference counting to be registered in the script engine.

Comment: Your code is OK, up to and including `ptr->SubRef()` call. There's one `allocate` call, and a matching `deallocate` call. No memory is leaked. However, the subsequent `ptr->RefSum()` call exhibits undefined behavior - you are calling a method of an object after its lifetime has ended.

Comment: Thank you for the appropriate answer Igor Tandetnik. I knew about the undefined behavior. I placed it there to actually point out the fact that I need that memory to be freed after the counter reaches 0.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Are you asking whether `alloc.deallocate(this, 1);` deallocates the memory? Yes, it does. Obviously.

Comment: _I placed it there to actually point out the fact that I need that memory to be freed after the counter reaches 0._ How does accessing freed memory point that out? The value will probably still be sitting in memory if nothing else has reused those bytes and so `0` will be printed out, but that doesn't tell you whether the memory was freed or not.

Comment: "How does accessing freed memory point that out?" I don't know :) I got confused. And yes my question was if `alloc.deallocate(this, 1);` actually frees the previously allocated memory. Why do the good answers have to be in the comments :-/

Comment: Can you really deallocate an object using a different `std::allocator` object than the one you allocated it with?

Comment: @Barmar, yes. All objects of type `std::allocator<X>` are equivalent, for all `X`.

Comment: @SanduLiviuCatalin, if you ask an unclear question you wil ltend to get responses in comments, because some people won't post an answer if they think they don't understand the question

Comment: well, thank you Igor Tandetnik and Jonathan Wakely for the appropriate answers. Sorry if the question as a little confusing. I was confused a little (a little more actually).

Comment: @Barmar Good point. That was one of the things that confused me. I didn't knew if two different allocator objects could destroy/deallocate the same instance. And if the correct memory is freed after.

Comment: `std::allocator`, in particular, is required by the standard to be stateless, its instances interchangeable. Other allocators may not be so forgiving. Be careful if you plan to generalize to an arbitrary allocator. And if you don't, then why this `allocate`/`contruct`/`destroy`/`deallocate` dance? Just do `new Test` to construct, and `delete` to destroy - it's equivalent to what `std::allocator` does.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik So that I can return an "Out Of Memory!" message/exception to the script engine when the memory cannot be allocated for the required instance. I don't like it either :)

Comment: I don't quite see how the conclusion follows from the premise. `new` throws `bad_alloc` just as happily as `allocator::allocate`.

Comment: Ok then. The script library used a similar method (except with C allocators) and I simply wen't with the flow. I though, who knows? Maybe it's how it's supposed to be :-/ Bu I'll look more into it and probably try to get rid of the current implementation. Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*So my question is: When m_Ref reaches 0 and the object is destructed and deallocated, is the previously allocated memory freed or not?*

Simple answer: yes. "free" and "deallocate" mean the same thing.